# Scroll bar is not showing on Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I want to apply scroll bar on Recycler view. Here is my code. The scroll bar is showing on XML but not on the app when code is compiled.

```
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/booking_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintHeight="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/listTopBarrier"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/booking_item_layout"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        
        />
```

[image: Scroll is showing in the XML.]

Comment: try to use android:scrollbarSize="4dp". Code is working. If the issue persists then upload the complete XML file